# Trying to delete from SQL and remove item and show message on modal

Tags: jquery, ajax

View page

```
 <a href="#" data-id='.$row['employee_id'].' data-target="#confirm-delete" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirm-delete">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
       <h1>Delete a Employee</h1>
        <div class="alert-success" style="display: none;">Successfully delete</div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="delete-form" value=""/>
          <p class="alert alert-error">Are you sure to delete ?</p>
          <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="">Yes</button>
              <a class="btn" href="view-list.php">No</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
  var valueID;

  $('.glyphicon-trash').click(function(){
    valueID = $(this).parent().data('id');
    console.log('id ' + valueID);
    $('#delete-form').val(valueID);
    $('.btn-danger').attr('data-id', valueID);
  });

  $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(e){
    var val = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: 'employee='+val,
        success: function(data){
          $('.alert-success').fadeIn(200).show();
          setTimeout(function(){
        $("#confirm-delete").modal('hide');
    }, 3000);

        },
        error: function(data){
          $('.alert-danger').html('Failed');
        }
    });
  });
```

when click button 'YES' on modal, then it should show the success message and then modal disappearing after 2 seconds. But the specific row doesn't disappear and also its data in row is not deleted as well. I couldn't figure why. Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
data-id='.$row['employee_id'].'
```

you used single quotes both for the HTML attribute and the hash key string. It may be mixing HTML with PHP code and not printing any value at all. Fixed version below:

```
data-id='.$row["employee_id"].'
```

Or maybe you should just write

```
<?php echo $row['employee_id']; ?>
```

It depends on how you're printing the HTML code. Also, always remember to sanitize user input. The line below has a security flaw:

```
data: 'employee='+val,
```

Anyone can delete others users by providing a different id or change the ***val*** value by editing the HTML form (with a browser developer tool like Firebug) to do something nasty like a ***DROP TABLE USERS;*** command.

Comment: Well, never trust the client, always sanitize on backend. For sure at frontend if you want.